# symfony2 service why inject param is string?

Tags: php, symfony, service

Hi i created a service and when i try ti use it i got an error
`ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Project\MyDriveBundle\Storage\LocalAdapter::__construct() must be an instance of Project\MainBundle\Manager\UserManager, string given, called in E:\wamp\www\project\src\Project\MyDriveBundle\Storage\LocalAdapter.php on line 41 and defined in E:\wamp\www\project\src\Project\MyDriveBundle\Storage\LocalAdapter.php line 38`

why is that ?
here is my service:

```
/**
 * @Service("local_adapter")
 */
class LocalAdapter
{

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesytem;

    /**
     * @var Adapter
     */
    private $adapter;

    /**
     * @var UserManager
     */
    protected $userManager;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *      "userManager" = @Inject("manager.user")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->adapter = new LocalAdapter('/' . $this->userManager->getUsername() . '/');
        $this->filesytem = new Filesystem($this->adapter);
    }

    public function getFilesytem()
    {
        return $this->filesytem;
    }

}
```

Comment: Need to see the service declaration.

Comment: I haven't used annotations for that so I can't be 100% sure, but typically service names start with a `@` when injecting as an argument.

Comment: no, you dont use `@` when useing annotations. the problem was becous i importet wrong class for my adapter. it was `use Gaufrette\Adapter;` and supposed to be `use Gaufrette\Adapter\Local as LocalAdapter;`
now it works. sorry for bother you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this includes on the top of page:

```
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("local_adapter")
 */
class LocalAdapter
{
    // other your code
```